# Expired cert for (Authentication Node.js Example Quickstart)

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit, jackhenry-jxchange

I am just beginning working with Banno and Jack Henry plugins and i am trying to run through the Node.js quickstart but have gotten an error trying to access the local host page.

I have succesfully started the server but when attempting to access the login via localhost:8080/login.html i receive a privacy error because the server.cert file contains an expired certificate. I need somewhere to generate a new certificate or where JH has one stored for the dev learning track. Thanks in advance

Comment: we've [updated the Consumer API OIDC Example](https://github.com/Banno/consumer-api-openid-connect-example/pull/37) and related [Authentication (Node.js Example) quickstart](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/quickstarts/authentication/) to make this easier on Windows machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser should give an option (even if it is somewhat hidden) to continue with the *Consumer API OpenID Connect Example* (https://localhost:8080/login.html) even though the cert has expired.

For example, with Safari for Mac it should look like this:

[image: This connection is not private, show details button]

Clicking the "Show Details" button brings up a hyperlink option to "visit this website". That'll let you move forward.

[image: This connection is not private, visit this website]

The precise steps may be different in your browser + operating system, but the general answer is the same.

[image: Consumer API OpenID Connect Example, Sign in with Banno]